# Creating and eMailing PDF within Livecode on iOS

Tags: ios, email, pdf, livecode

My app (running on an iPad) is generating a PDF which is then attached to an email and sent to a client.  However when I receive the PDF, Adobe will not open it.  This is the error I get:

> Acrobat could not open
>   'Invoice 6020130304036.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type
>   or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an
>   email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

I have created the same PDF on my development environment (Mac) and the file opens ok.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/Invoice " & tInvoice & ".pdf" into tPDFPath
open printing to pdf tPDFPath     
print card "Invoice" of this stack from 340,0 to 1010,650 into 20,10,575,550
close printing
put tPDFPath into tAttachments["data"]
put "PDF" into tAttachments["type"]
put "Invoice" into tAttachments["name"]
mobileComposeMail tSubject, tTo, tCCs, tBCCs, tBody, tAttachments
```

Has anyone else experienced similar issues?

TIA, AA.

Comment: If you provided a sample broken pdf, wer could check in what way it is broken. that might give a hint where to look for the culprit.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the PDF after all @mkl.  The statement should read: put tPDFPath into tAttachments["file"] not ["data"].  Thank you for replying though.